# how to do conditional formating in a chunk, colorizing number from 0 to5, 5 to 10,...?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to apply a conditional formatting within a chunk of data? I mean, suppose we have a coulms that has more than 1000 rows; starting with 0 and ending with number 915.7. I wanted to sort the sheet based on this columns and then colorize this columns in a chunk of 5. for example all numbers that are between 0 and 5 to be green, between 5 and 10 be yellow between 10 to 15 orange.... all the way to 915 to 920.

Is that possible?

Comment: Conditional formatting: select the column and the choose a Color for <=5 and another <=10 etc

Comment: @Solar Mike  my column has numbers from 0 ro 917.5. I want to colorize all of them not just between 10 to 15. and of course I don't want to write that many condition manually up until 920!  Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

#### Original (see edit below)

It's easy enough to create the conditional formats. The hard part is that you'll need to specify more than 180 colors that are clearly different, and meaningful to you. That's not as simple as the "green, yellow, orange" in your question. With that many colors the differences between them will be subtle. You might have to settle for fewer colors and a larger increment, e.g., <=50, <=100, <=150, etc. I suspect it won't make sense unless you limit it to maybe 20 colors at most. Or if they're sorted, you might cycle through a small number of colors that repeat after every 25 or so.

The code below simply loops with an index running from 5 to 920 in increments of 5, creating a new conditional format each loop.

As an illustration of how to specify the colors here, the code just sets the color to the loop index times 30 to create (slightly) different color values each loop. I'm not even going to try to figure out how to specify the colors you want; I'll leave that up to you. But this code won't do you any good unless you can figure out how to specify that many colors meaningfully. Good luck!

```
Sub ConditionalFormat()
    Dim wkshFormat As Worksheet, rngHighlight As Range, nIndex As Integer
    
    Set wkshFormat = ActiveSheet
    With wkshFormat
        Set rngHighlight = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) ' Column A, from A1 to the last entry 
    End With
    
    For nIndex = 5 To 920 Step 5
        With rngHighlight.FormatConditions _
            .Add(Type:=xlCellValue, _
            Operator:=xlLessEqual, _
            Formula1:=nIndex)  ' <=5, <=10, etc.
            
            .StopIfTrue = True
            .Interior.Color = nIndex * 30 ' A simple way to specify colors
        End With
        
    Next nIndex
    
End Sub
```

#### Edit

Since your data are sorted, using a repeating set of colors might work. That would result in bands of colors for similar values (see screen shot). Then you could easily specify the colors using the `ColorIndex` property instead of an actual color value. Excel provides a set of 56 colors. Many of them are too dark for me to read, but I find the 8 colors in the range from 33-40 easy to read, at least to my eyes. To apply that approach, change one line in the code:

```
.Interior.Color = nIndex * 30
```

becomes

```
.Interior.ColorIndex = nIndex Mod (8) + 33
```

In that statement, `nIndex Mod(8)` returns values 0-7; adding 33 yields 33-40 as color indexes. If you need more colors you could create an array of your preferred colors and cycle through the array index.

I found this color chart useful (the web has plenty of others):
https://www.excelsupersite.com/what-are-the-56-colorindex-colors-in-excel/

[image: Conditional colors applied as ColorIndex]